# How to add another html tag (i.e. span) before the field value renders using hook_preprocess()?

Tags: entities, hooks, theming

I have a field (field_txt) that renders properly, but now i want to add a  tag around it so that i can style the background color of it. How would this be possible using the preprocess field hook?

Output

```
<div>some text value</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
<div><span class="bg-color-rd">some txt value</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it would be done with a preprocess hook, but an alternative would be to instead copy [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) into your theme, rename it according to the convention of field-name-[field_name], and simply add the `<span>` and `</span>` elements at the appropriate points in the template, like so:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <span class="bg-color-rd">
        <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
        <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
            <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
            <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I did not use a field template override, but your suggesttion lead me down the path of writing a custom module to call hooK_preprocess_entity and hook_preprocess_field in which i was able to add the desired class using the #prefix and #suffix attributes.

Comment: Good call. That's probably a cleaner way of doing it anyway.